# MS Access 2007 VBA DAO.Relation object mysteriously gets unset. What's going on?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I got this sample code:

```
<!-- language: lang-vb -->

Option Compare Database

Private Function get_relation() As String
  get_relation = CurrentDb.Relations(1).name
  Debug.Print "Inside get_relation() relation name is " & get_relation
' Inside get_relation() relation name is Table1Table2
  Debug.Print "Again, the name is " & CurrentDb.Relations(get_relation).name
' Again, the name is Table1Table2
End Function

Public Sub test()
  Dim R As DAO.Relation, name As String
  name = get_relation()
  Debug.Print "Outside, the name is still " & name
' Outside, the name is still Table1Table2
  Set R = CurrentDb.Relations(name)
  Debug.Print "Again, the name is " & R.name
' At the line above it throws error!
End Sub
```

The output is:

```
Inside get_relation() relation name is Table1Table2
Again, the name is Table1Table2
Outside, the name is still Table1Table2
```

Then there's an error:

```
Runtime error '3420':
Object invalid or no longer set.
```

This is what I see in Watches:

```
Watch :   : Name : "Table1Table2" : String : Playground.test
Watch : - : CurrentDb.Relations(Name) :  : Object/Relation : Playground.test
   : Attributes : <Object invalid or no longer set.> : Long : Playground.test
   : Fields : <Object invalid or no longer set.> : Fields : Playground.test
   : ForeignTable : <Object invalid or no longer set.> : String : Playground.test
   : Name : <Object invalid or no longer set.> : String : Playground.test
   : PartialReplica : <Object invalid or no longer set.> : Boolean : Playground.test
   : Properties : <Object invalid or no longer set.> : Properties : Playground.test
   : Table : <Object invalid or no longer set.> : String : Playground.test
Watch : - : R :  : Relation/Relation : Playground.test
   : Attributes : <Object invalid or no longer set.> : Long : Playground.test
   : Fields : <Object invalid or no longer set.> : Fields : Playground.test
   : ForeignTable : <Object invalid or no longer set.> : String : Playground.test
   : Name : <Object invalid or no longer set.> : String : Playground.test
   : PartialReplica : <Object invalid or no longer set.> : Boolean : Playground.test
   : Properties : <Object invalid or no longer set.> : Properties : Playground.test
   : Table : <Object invalid or no longer set.> : String : Playground.test
```

So, at some point my DAO.Relation R gets unset (or at least all it's members gets unset). Further more CurrentDB.Relations("Table1Table2") and CurrentDB.Relations(1) are in the same state (all members are invalid or unset).

At the same time CurrentDB.Relations inspected via watches show that all members are set, and everything seems to be ok.

I know my question is not very specific, but I really don't get it. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning to R using CurrentDb rather than an explicit variable so it is going out of scope. Instead use:-

```
dim db as dao.database
set db = currentdb
...
dim r as dao.relation
set r = db.relations (rname)
```

("name" is not a good name for a variable as it is a reserved word.)

Comment: Thanks. That solved my problem, but I still don't get it. Where exactly is `CurrentDB` going out of scope? I thought it's a global variable. And if it's out of scope, why do I see it in watches (including `CurrentDB.relations`)? And if I see it in watches, why don't I see `CurrentDB.Relations(1)`? It all seems bizzare to me.

Comment: I probably used an incorrect term - it is not so much a matter of scope as the nature of CurrentDB. It is not treated as an object in the way that you can treat an explicitly declared object. See here for some more explanation: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/hu/accessdev/thread/7ea9506f-5e91-4896-80b9-6712762388ea

Comment: Good link. That explains a lot. Thank you. I've spent two working days trying to figure out what's going on. Now I just hope I won't have to work with VBA too often. It seems so unfriendly :(